# What will I need to send Video over bluetooth or WiFi to Android phone

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, android, video-transmitter

I don't know much about electorics I'm programmer and know some stuff about digital electronics that I learn at school, but I have this idea to send video data from a camera (I found on [Alibaba CCD boards](http://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText=ccd%20board) you can get bare CCD board or CMOS and buy a lens for it or get it with a lens) to Android app that will allow to take pictures like with native camera.

I want something realy small. something like this [Hidden mini dv camera](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/1272784548/720P_HD_Hidden_mini_dv_camera.html).

What else except CCD board and WiFi or Bluetooth board I will need in order for it to work? (I was thinking about using Arduino but it seams that it's too slow to handle Video).

It will be possible to modify that button camera to send video to a phone?

Or maybe something like this already exists and only need Android App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need something that is effectively a "computer" with a fair amount of buffer memory, and if using a bare camera a suitable camera interface channel or a lot of glue logic in an FPGA.  For example, for some very specific cameras you could do this with a raspberry pi.

If you want to do so at any video-like update rate, you will need wifi, not bluetooth.

On the phone (at least one recent enough to have the power to do software video decoding), plugging into this with your own app won't be too unrealistically difficult (there are comparable apps on the market), but making it so that other existing apps would use this camera would require heavily modifying the Android installation.

Likely the simplest/cheapest way to do what you want to do would be to use an existing wifi camera, or else use a second (older?) Android phone as the remote camera (though pursuing such an approach would point towards moving the question to stackoverflow since it would no longer be about hardware design)